# Regular Expression ignore characters in between two characters on different lines

Tags: java, .net, regex

Hi I am trying to get some values, skip the remainder of the values for that line, and then get the next line, but only if it is a certain pattern.  So my data is like

```
($ Amount)Tj 1 0 0 1 18.4 369.8 Tm
 (12/30)Tj 1 0 0 1 84.7 369.8 Tm
 (CLUBZONE.COM TICKETS USA VANCOUVER BC)Tj 1 0 0 1 449.5 369.8 Tm
 (-165.00)Tj 1 0 0 1 18.4 356.8 Tm
 (01/05)Tj 1 0 0 1 84.7 356.8 Tm
```

And I want to grab `(12/30)(CLUBZONE.COM TICKETS USA VANCOUVER BC)(-165.00)`

Should i be matching the date, then everything until the newline character, the the next thing for the next line?  I want to omit the things outside of the paranthesis right now I just have this

```
[\(][0-1][1-9]/[1-3][0-9][\)]
```

*Note the data is coming in as a new line after each `Tm`

Comment: Is this Java or .net? You should pick one to get a definitive answer.

Comment: err I havent really chosen one.  I will do either but I woudl rather .NET

Comment: Do you want to only retrieve the values in the first parenthesis on every line?

Comment: In your case it's much easier to get for each line from second till penultimate character before `Tj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built this regex in RegexBuddy for PCRE with dot matching newline:

```
^.*?(\(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}\)).*?(\(.*?\)).*?(\(-?\d+\.\d{2}\)).*$
```

Then the replacement is:

```
$1$2$3
```

Answer (score 1):

`(?<value>\(.*\))` matches your example. Here is the corresponding code in `C#`

```
private IList<string> GetValues(string input)
{
    const string pattern = @"(?<value>\(.*\))";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var values = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
    {
        values.Add(match.Groups["value"].Value.ToString());
    }

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\([0-1][1-9]/[1-3][0-9]\))(?:Tj[\d\s\.]*Tm)\s*(\(.*\))(?:Tj[\d\s\.]*Tm)\s*(\([-\d\.]*\))
```

Quick and dirty, only tested in Visual REGEXP, but this should get what you want, in matches 1 through 3.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!  And then to delete the stuff outside the paranthesis I think it shoudl be pretty easy?

Comment: oh i think josh has it below